# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) in 8.1 devices native crash

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, crash, android-webview

A strange crash is occuring suddenly in my production build , i added last update in januvary no changes and all was going good, suddenly the following crash start to appear on my crash console

it says **signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)**

with following log

> *****               ***** pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> my pakage name <<<
>
> backtrace:
>       #00  pc 000000000067ea5c  /data/app/com.android.chrome-vZF2piAAwh-WP-UolouoNg==/base.apk
>       #01  pc 000000000067c0b4  /data/app/com.android.chrome-vZF2piAAwh-WP-UolouoNg==/base.apk

i understand its not any logical error,i googled and find the [This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/I6giN0VbVa0%5B1-25%5D)

But at end of forum they saying it wont fix, i dont understand suddenly how a crash is occuring.There are some webviews in my app no ad mob i am using, i read some form saying its admob issue but am not using any ad mob, my app is add free

The crash occur in 8.1 version suddenly 3 days back, Some of the device am listing below

Redmi Note 5 Pro (whyred)   23  63.9%
B2017G (tulip)  9   25.0%
Redmi S2 (ysl)  2   5.6%
Redmi 5 Plus (vince)    1   2.8%
POCO F1 (beryllium)     1   2.8%

Can any one tell me how to resolve this issue